# Django - best way of storing data created on the fly for a view/template

Tags: python, django

i need to send some data to a template in the format of

```
template_name: RTR-01
device_name: EDGE

templte_name: RTR-02
device_name: EDGE

template_name: SW-01
device_name: CORE
```

and so on.

i know i cant use a list as they only allow one value, would a class be best suited? and how do i create a class on the fly? also this data is not stored in the DB its built on the fly

EDIT:

Current config for the dynamic data below, i take the template name which is in the format STR-RTR-01, then i put the location name in the middle to make STR-UK-RTR-01. in my dictionary i need both the before and after result, how do i create the dictionary on the fly in this manner?

```
showroom_devices = []
for item in config_templates:
    if item['device_name'].startswith("STR-"):
        device = item['device_name']
        completed_device_name = device[:4] + modelShowroom.location.upper()[:4] + "-" + device[4:]
        showroom_devices.append(completed_device_name)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data in a list of dictionaries:

```python
data = [
    {
        "template_name": "RTR-01",
        "device_name": "EDGE"
    },
    {
        "template_name": "SW-01",
        "device_name": "CORE"
    },
]
```

Then you will need to update the template's context by overriding the `render_to_response` method.

```python
def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
    context.update({"data": data})
    return super().render_to_response(context, **kwargs)
```

And then you can iterate in your template

```python
<ul>
{% for item in data %}
<li>{{item.template_name}}</li>
<li>{{item.device_name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ive added my current config, to the question, i need to know how to dynamically create a dictionary for it to add to my list?

Comment: `showroom_devices.append({"before": device, "after": completed_device_name})`

Answer (score 0):

A `list` of `dict`s seems best suited:

```
context = [
    {
        'template_name': 'RTR-01',
        'device': 'EDGE',
    },
    {
        'template_name': 'RTR-02',
        'device': 'EDGE',
    },
    {
        'template_name': 'SW-01',
        'device': 'CORE',
    },
]
```

You use classes when you want to associate behaviour to your data, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: ive added my current config, to the question, i need to know how to dynamically create a dictionary for it to add to my list?